# inheriting from std::ostream (to avoid rewriting same old content)...?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

I would like to have some C++11 output  stream which writes to a file only if the newly written content is different from the former one (if the content is the same as the one existing on disk, I don't want to alter the original file's metadata).

FWIW, the program is on GNU/Linux/Debian/Sid x86-64, compiled by a recent [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) (or later). It is a server-like program, and there is only at most one process running it. No other process is supposed to write to that file on the system.

The reason I want to avoid overwriting an existing identical file content is because the actual output is some `*.h` C++ header file .... (if that matters, it is a new incarnation of a future [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) monitor, I am redesigning & rewriting [this](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor) in C++11) and I don't want future `make` builds to recompile stuff depending on it if that generated header file has not changed.

I'm tempted to inherit from `std::ofstream` (then, the initial file path would be some temporary path name) or `std::ostringstream`  (then, the entire file content is kept in memory, not a big deal for my case), and redefine its `close` method to compare the new content with the old content on disk, and rewrite the disk file only if that content changes.

But I feel it smells not good (or even wrong), in particular because [std::ofstream::close](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/close) is not documented as `virtual`. Should I use [std::filebuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) instead?

I have many existing [`operator <<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) with the left operand being `std::ostream&`  and the right one being some of my own classes, and I would like to use them on my special streams.
I have already lots of functions able to output to any `std::ostream` and I would like to use some of them on such a "differential" file stream...

Or should I inherit from `std::ostream` (hence I slightly changed the title of the question which initially mentioned `std::ofstream`, not `std::ostream`)?

I will compare the old and new content at close time (just by closing the temporary file, and reading it and the old file, and comparing them byte by byte).

Comment: Sounds like this is not the job of a file stream. A stream is a flow of data (in this case, destined for file storage), but it isn't a file.

Comment: Why? How is that different, e.g. from `popen` in C?

Comment: What do you suggest? I have many functions using `std::ostream` and I want them to be able to output to such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't. A stream is a flow of data, not a file. It's not appropriate to let this functionality go anywhere near streams. If nothing else, although you could probably hack a way to determine early on whether the source and destination were identical, that would break the FIFO model of streams. They're just not the right tool for this job.

Generate your file to a temporary location, then perform an `md5sum` comparison and move it (via overwriting) to the target path *iff* the content differs; else simply remove the temporary file. Surely it needn't be any more complicated than that.

Comment: The point is that I want these things to be usable as `std::ostream` as transparently as possible

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Well, as explained, I just think that's a terrible idea. As a programmer using your code this would be extremely surprising, and more than a little confusing. The semantics and behaviour and potential edge cases would not be clear to me at all. You are trying to treat a stream like something other than a stream. Ultimately, I can't stop you though. :)

Comment: What edge cases are you thinking of?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I cannot tell you what they are, because they are unexpected. Without knowing more about how you determine whether two files are identical, and in what chunk size the new data is made available, and how your code is structured, it is impossible to answer that. The question is simply too vague.

Answer (score 1):

My mental model of this is that it's the `streambuf` that is the internal implementor's interface and the `stream` is just the wrapper that makes it convenient to use. So to change functionality you normally define things at the `streambuf` level, where there are lots of virtual functions to override. But I'm far from an expert on this.

You might, with care, be able to use your modified `filebuf` with a vanilla `ofstream`.

Answer (score 1):

Although writing a new streambuf might be the way to go, one approach is that your new class *is-a* ostream that *has-a* fstream internally.  That is, it inherits from the abstract base class and has a private data member representing the underlying file.